Wrangling Pandas Dataframe
I have a large dataframe that looks like below.
PERIOD    Value
1         30
1         40
1         50
2         60
2         75
2         80
3         90
3         100
3         200

I want to have the DataFrame in following format without using for loop.
PERIOD     Value
1          30
2          60
3          90
1          40
2          75
3         100
1          50
2          80
3         200

The order of entries has to be maintained. Any help is appreciated.

You can use groupby.cumcount to (stably) sort the values then use the index to reorder:
order = df.groupby('PERIOD').cumcount().sort_values(kind='stable').index

out = df.loc[order]

Variant using the key parameter of sort_values:
out = df.sort_values(by='PERIOD', kind='stable',
                     key=lambda x: x.groupby(x).cumcount())

Output:
   PERIOD  Value
0       1     30
3       2     60
6       3     90
1       1     40
4       2     75
7       3    100
2       1     50
5       2     80
8       3    200

Explanation of the logic
We de-duplicate the PERIOD with cumcount, then use this value to perform a stable sort.
   PERIOD  Value  cumcount  stable_order
0       1     30         0             0
1       1     40         1             3
2       1     50         2             6
3       2     60         0             1
4       2     75         1             4
5       2     80         2             7
6       3     90         0             2
7       3    100         1             5
8       3    200         2             8


This works perfectly. Would you please explain the piece of code?

@S_Scouse sure, I added the intermediates to explain the logic
